# Excel formula with Multiple text and a number condition

Tags: excel, average, formulas

I am trying to find an average of 1 column if the number in the column is greater than 0 and another column is either a C or a P.  I was trying to use the Averageifs formula but its is not giving the correct information.

Here is a sample of the table with some dummy data:

```
Column G   Column H
Type (L,S,C,P)  Proft/Loss
C    $153.00 
L    $(25.00)
P    $(10.00)
S    $15.00 
C    $20.00 
L    $100.00 
P    $(50.00)
S    $(150.00)
C    $(50.00)
P    $(52.00)
L    $75.00 
S    $(75.00)
C    $50.00 
P    $75.00 
L    $150.00 
S    $(10.00)
```

These are the formulas I have tried:

```
 =AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS($H$29:$H$1000,$G$29:$G$1000,({"C","P"}),$H$29:$H$1000,">0"))
=AVERAGEIFS($H$29:$H$1000,$G$29:$G$1000,({"C","P"}),$H$29:$H$1000,">0")
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($G$29:$G$1000, {"C","P"},">0")), $H$29:$H$1000))
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you!  Both formulas worked and helped immensely.

Comment: Mark the one you used as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer. It will mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the first will return two numbers; one for the `C` and one for the `P` and then average the two, which gives too much weight to `p` in your data set.

The second will only do the first array value

The third will  need some work to the MATCH for two criteria and is entered as an array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

I propose:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,({"C","P"}),H:H,">0"))/SUM(COUNTIFS(G:G,({"C","P"}),H:H,">0"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A17="C",IF(B2:B17>0,B2:B17,"NO"),IF(A2:A17="P",IF(B2:B17>0,B2:B17,"NO"),"NO")))
```

Hope that helps.